# Consulta SQL usando dos count()

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla playlist, playlist_track, playlist_adversiting. Intento realizar una consulta donde retorne todos los registro de playlist con la cantidad correspondiente a sus otras tablas:

SQL:

```
SELECT
   playlist.*,
   user_created.user_id as user_created_id,
   user_created.user_name as user_created_name,
   user_updated.user_id as user_updated_id,
   user_updated.user_name  as user_updated_name,
   COUNT( playlist_track.playlist_track_id ) as track_count,
   COUNT( playlist_advertising.playlist_advertising_id ) AS advertising_count

FROM playlist

INNER JOIN user user_created ON user_created.user_id = playlist.playlist_createdBy
INNER JOIN user user_updated ON user_updated.user_id = playlist.playlist_updatedBy

LEFT JOIN playlist_track ON playlist_track.playlist_track_id_playlist = playlist.playlist_id

LEFT JOIN playlist_advertising ON playlist_advertising.playlist_advertising_id_playlist = playlist.playlist_id

GROUP BY
    playlist.playlist_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que tendrias que hacer es un subquery para tener la cantidad.

```
           (SELECT COUNT(playlist_track.playlist_track_id) 
              FROM playlist_track 
             WHERE playlist_track.playlist_track_id_playlist = playlist.playlist_id) as `# playlist_track`,
           (SELECT COUNT(playlist_advertising.playlist_advertising_id) 
                  FROM playlist_advertising 
             WHERE playlist_advertising.playlist_advertising_id_playlist = playlist.playlist_id) as `# playlist_advertising`
FROM playlist
```